# Why is CiviCRM 5.38 making search fields on a directory listing display using a "ui-spinner-input"?

Tags: profile, search, ui, directory

I've got a site that displays a searchable directory of organisations using a CiviCRM profile. When I use the search facility ('Edit Search Criteria') the fields all appear to be displayed using a weird "ui-spinner-input" that seems purpose built to confuse users. This seems to apply regardless of the field type being searched. I can only assume this is some weird bug?

Comment: Can you reproduce it on dmaster?

Comment: I'm wondering whether the theme is doing this? It's a WP site.